# Field 'article' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The application has the functionality of adding news to Favorites.I have created a Favorites page where the news is taken from the database.
But it gives the error "Field 'article' has not been initialized".
It is associated with the "Details" button, which should open the full article when clicked.How can this error be resolved?
Page Code Favorites:

```js
import '../models/article_model.dart';

class FavScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  const FavScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FavScreen> createState() => _FavScreenState();
}

class _FavScreenState extends State<FavScreen> {
  late final Article article;
  final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('favoriteItems');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Favorite News', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff27935),
      ),
      body:
         StreamBuilder(
           stream: _fireStore.snapshots(),
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
             if(!snapshot.hasData) {
               return Text('No featured news');
             } else {
               return ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     return InkWell(
                       child: Container(
                         margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             color: Colors.white,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                             boxShadow: [
                               BoxShadow(
                                 color: Colors.black12,
                                 blurRadius: 3.0,
                               ),
                             ]),
                         child: Column(
                           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                           children: [
                             Container(
                               height: 200.0,
                               width: double.infinity,
                               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                 image: DecorationImage(
                                     image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('image')), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                               ),
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 8.0,
                             ),
                             Container(
                                 child: Row(
                                     textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                     children: <Widget>[
                                       Container(
                                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                           color: Color(0xfff27935),
                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                         ),
                                         child: Text(
                                           snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('name'),
                                           style: TextStyle(
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                       IconButton(
                                           onPressed: () {
                                             _fireStore.doc(snapshot.data?.docs[index].id).delete();
                                           },
                                           icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_remove)),
                                     ]
                                 )
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 8.0,
                             ),
                             Text(
                               snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('title'),
                               style: TextStyle(
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                 fontSize: 16.0,
                               ),
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 10.0,
                             ),
                             GestureDetector(
                               onTap: () {
                                 Navigator.push(
                                     context,
                                     MaterialPageRoute(
                                         builder: (context) =>
                                             ArticlePage(
                                               article: article,
                                             )));
                               },
                               child: new Text("DETAILS", style: TextStyle(
                                 fontSize: 12.0,
                               ),),
                             )
                           ],
                         ),
                       ),
                     );
                   }
               );
             }
           },
         )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It literally says what's wrong. you never initialize `article`

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: "field" hasn't been initialized. `late final Article article;`
The variable `article` is null when you pass it to `ArticlePage` class constructor.

```
ArticlePage( article: article );
```