# How to properly initialize a variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The application has a Favorites page, where news from the database that the user has saved is added.Each news card has a "Details" button, when clicked, it opens the news page.But the problem is that I get the error "Field 'article' has not been initialized".How can I properly initialize this variable so that the error disappears?
On the general news page, the button works, namely, on the Favorites page, an error occurs.
Featured news page code(Update):

```js
class FavScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FavScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FavScreen> createState() => _FavScreenState();
}

class _FavScreenState extends State<FavScreen> {
  late final Article article;
  final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('favoriteItems');

  @override
  void initState() {
    article = Article(
      author: article.author,
      title: article.title,
      description: article.description,
      url: article.url,
      urlToImage: article.urlToImage,
      publishedAt: article.publishedAt,
      content: article.content,
      source: article.source,
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Favorite News', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff27935),
      ),
      body:
         StreamBuilder(
           stream: _fireStore.snapshots(),
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
             if(!snapshot.hasData) {
               return Text('No featured news');
             } else {
               return ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     return InkWell(
                       child: Container(
                         margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             color: Colors.white,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                             boxShadow: [
                               BoxShadow(
                                 color: Colors.black12,
                                 blurRadius: 3.0,
                               ),
                             ]),
                         child: Column(
                           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                           children: [
                             Container(
                               height: 200.0,
                               width: double.infinity,
                               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                 image: DecorationImage(
                                     image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('image')), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                               ),
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 8.0,
                             ),
                             Container(
                                 child: Row(
                                     textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                     children: <Widget>[
                                       Container(
                                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                           color: Color(0xfff27935),
                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                         ),
                                         child: Text(
                                           snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('name'),
                                           style: TextStyle(
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                       IconButton(
                                           onPressed: () {
                                             _fireStore.doc(snapshot.data?.docs[index].id).delete();
                                           },
                                           icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_remove)),
                                     ]
                                 )
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 8.0,
                             ),
                             Text(
                               snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('title'),
                               style: TextStyle(
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                 fontSize: 16.0,
                               ),
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 10.0,
                             ),
                             GestureDetector(
                               onTap: () {
                                 Navigator.push(
                                     context,
                                     MaterialPageRoute(
                                         builder: (context) =>
                                             ArticlePage(
                                               article: article,
                                             )));
                               },
                               child: new Text("DETAILS", style: TextStyle(
                                 fontSize: 12.0,
                               ),),
                             )
                           ],
                         ),
                       ),
                     );
                   }
               );
             }
           },
         )
    );
  }
}
```

News page code:

```js
import 'package:news_app/models/article_model.dart';


class ArticlePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Article article;

  ArticlePage({required this.article});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(article.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff27935),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(article.urlToImage), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xfff27935),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              ),
              child: Text(
                article.source.name,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Text(
              article.content,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You posted this question already, and it was answered properly. No need to repost the same question within 24h.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Field 'article' has not been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71854241/field-article-has-not-been-initialized)

Comment: If the previous time did not answer your question, you should edit to refine your question, and/or use the comment section there to ask for clarification from the person who gave you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize or assign a value or values to the variable article, you can do it in `initState` so before building the view the variable will be initialize:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // verityFirstRun();
    article = Article( properties: values );
    super.initState();
  }
```

Here another example:

```
class _DropDownCoursesState extends State<DropDownCourses> {
  
  late String? text1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    text1 = "hello"; // assing a value to the variable
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(text1!), // then use it
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

About late in the dart documentation:

> The late modifier means “enforce this variable’s constraints at
> runtime instead of at compile time”. It’s almost like the word “late”
> describes when it enforces the variable’s guarantees.
>
> In this case, since the variable is not definitely initialized, every
> time the field is read, a runtime check is inserted to make sure it
> has been assigned a value. If it hasn’t, an exception is thrown.
> Giving the variable the type String means “you should never see me
> with a value other than a string” and the late modifier means “verify
> that at runtime”.

Late will trust you to initialize that variable at `compile time`, this is the reason why you must assign a value to the late variable before `runtime`

More info in: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables

Comment: Can you please tell me what parameters should I pass to the Article?I have added an Article model to the question

Comment: You have to fill it with the parameters listed in the `Article class` for example `author, title, description` however all the properties are in the Article class.

Comment: Unfortunately your option with initState didn't work.

Comment: Would you please show the changes that you applied?

Comment: Added updated code to the question

Comment: I see that in InitState, article object is receiving the same article variable in it one of them is `article.author`, but you cannot assign the same variable to itself, the value should come elsewhere, maybe those varibles migth come from `_fireStore`.

Comment: Could you write in more detail please? Did I pass Article parameters incorrectly?